# Extjs 6- filter grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, grid

I have textfield where I can filter a grid, the problem is it can't filter all column but only one of this, so I want to filter all column with any value enter on the textfield, even it's `type or name or email or something`, like a gridsearch. Thanks

snippet of my code:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
label: 'search',
emptyText: 'Enter type...',
listeners: {
           change: function (field, value) {
                   var grid = this.up('grid'),
                       store = grid.getStore();
                       if (!value) {
                            store.getFilters().removeAll();
                       } else {
                            store.filter([{property:'type',//can be other property
                                           value:value}]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your store has remoteFilter: true, you can use a custom filter function, as explained here
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.util.Filter.html

If your store has remoteFilter: false, you need to address the custom filtering server side, implementing an OR clause.